# Get extension of file without providing extension in the path

Tags: c#

Is it possible to get the extension of a file but when you specify the entire path other than the extension? For example:

C:\Users\Administrator\Pictures\BlueHillsTest

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[`Directory.GetFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f.aspx) will allow you to specify a wildcard for files to search:

```
System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\temp\py\", "test.*")
```

for me, returns an array of 3 matching items.  I *expect* an array, since the directory contains `test.cover`, `test.py`, and `test.pyc`.

If I use the `First` extension method:

```
System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\temp\py\", "test.*").First()
```

then it only returns the first result (`test.cover`).

However, using the `Single` extension method:

```
System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\temp\py\", "test.*").Single()
```

raises an `InvalidOperationException` because the "Sequence contains more than one element" (which might be what you want, depending on your circumstances).

But if I try

```
System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\temp\py\", "step.*").Single()
```

then I get just `step.py` (no exception raised) because that's the only file matching `step.*` in that directory.

Answer (score 2):

No it is not possible as you might have both `BlueHillsTest.xxx` and `BlueHillsTest.yyy` in this location. Which one do you expect to return in this case?

Comment: maybe return an array of all extensions.