# C++ Get File Extension Without Providing Extension In The Path

Tags: c++, file

I have a bunch of images called Apple-1, ..., Apple-n but I don't know if Apple-x is a .jpeg or .png and I want to determine that without knowing that it's a .jpeg or something else.

What I know is how the images are labeled and I want to get their extensions into a string (not all in one string, I would check for every image).
I appreciate any ideas :)

(There was a similar question asked here, but that's for C#: [Get extension of file without providing extension in the path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3055289/get-extension-of-file-without-providing-extension-in-the-path))

Comment: All an extension really is, is a part of the filename

Comment: How are you going to access the file if you don't know the filename?

Comment: Are the extensions there but you don't get them for some reason or are they completely missing from the file? What platform are you on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily do that with `boost::filesystem`:

**Example**

```
boost::filesystem::path folder(boost::filesystem::current_path());
for (boost::filesystem::directory_iterator it(folder), end; 
     it != end; ++it)
{
    auto ext = it->path().extension();
    if (ext == ".jpeg")
    {
        std::cout << "is jpeg" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this could work, i'll try that, thanks. Can i assume that ext will always be a string or are there other possibilities?

Comment: @Auberotte: `ext` is of type `boost::filesystem::path`. If you want a string, use the `string()` function, i.e. `std::string str = ext.string();`.

Comment: Hi, just wanted to test your solution but my compiler complains about ext, saying that ext does not name a type and was not declared in this scope. Do i have to include something else except boost/filesystem.hpp?

Comment: @Auberotte: [Here is a full example of the code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=67326d02eac6156ead2b93bd1881be98-f674c1a6d04c632b71a62362c0ccfc51). You will have to be compiling in C++11 mode and also link to boost filesystem and probably boost system. If you have any more trouble please let me know the compiler and names of the libs on your pc.

Comment: Ok, another problem appeared of which i don't know where it came from :) I get the same errors like those main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x233): undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'

main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x23f): undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'

main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x24b): undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()' and i get them in my main where i don't even use boost

Comment: Do you have any idea what's wrong here: http://pastie.org/8231149? I'm desperate :/

Comment: Finally works, but i'm wondering in which order it traverses the files O.o

Answer (score 0):

The boost filesystem library offers an excellent set of functions for this and related path issues" see [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#class-path)